# :not selector in css not working

Tags: html, css

Please refer below code

html:

```
<a href="#" class="red">AA</a>
<a href="#" class="navitem dropdown-toggle">BB</a>
<a href="#" class="user-nav">CC</a>
<a href="#">DD</a>
```

i want to apply the color except two anchors which contains the following classes **"navitem dropdown-toggle" and "user-nav"**

css:

```
:not(a[class="navitem dropdown-toggle"]), :not(a[class="user-nav"]) {
    color:#C71444 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

but color is not applied for first and last anchor tags.nothing gets worked. why ?

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QymZq/1/

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Comment: Using both of those `:not` selector actually selects **none** of the anchors since they all meet one of the two conditions. 3 of them aren't `.user-nav` and 3 of them aren't `navitem dropdown-toggle`. **What exactly are you trying to do?**

Comment: i need to select th other anchors which not contains the specified classes in question. see the answer updated by Quentin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, your syntax is invalid: from [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn)

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector

and

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

so, if we were to simply fix your syntax we would get:

```
:not(a):not([class="navitem dropdown-toggle"]), :not(a):not([class="user-nav"]) {
    color:#C71444 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

However,  you **do** want it to match `a` elements.

```
a:not([class="navitem dropdown-toggle"]), a:not([class="user-nav"]) {
    color:#C71444 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

However, even with this the ruleset will apply if something `a:not([class="navitem dropdown-toggle"])` **or** if something is `a:not([class="navitem dropdown-toggle"])` and that means everything (since those two selectors cannot apply to the same element).

It looks like you actually want:

```
a:not([class="navitem dropdown-toggle"]):not([class="user-nav"]) {
    color:green !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Beautifully explained and exact, it should be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly the same, but it may do the job

```
a:not(.navitem):not(.user-nav):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
    color:#C71444 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

But try to avoid `:not` as it is performance killer.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/QymZq/2/)

Comment: I was writing an answer but instead I will just add a demo to yours.

Comment: I ended up with exactly same rule and was going to post it but you got it first :)